# Personalize SMS in Data Extraction?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect

I am trying to create a SMS "Hello "NAME" how can i help you?" where name will dynamically change to each name in my data extraction.

But i am failing to get send a SMS with the personalisation as it usually just appears blank where the name should be.

My data extraction (named `SMS_MM_TEST`) contains these columns title, forename, surname, mobile_no, locale, email address. With email address set as the subscriber Key.

Answer (score 0):

In Contact Builder , under your Mobile Connect schema, add the necessary fields you wish to personalise with. The import your contacts to Mobile Connect and map the fields.

You can then use %%Personalisation%% fields in your SMS.

The alternative would be to use Ampscript in your SMS body to lookup the value from the data extension.

A word of caution regarding using personalisation in SMS is to consider the maximum length of the field you are inserting e.g. forename. People can have a variety of lengths of a name e.g. will, William, Billy so the character length of your SMS will vary and could push you over 160 limit.